# Does independent marginal distribution indicate independent conditional expectation?

Tags: probability, independence, conditional-expectation

Let's say, $z=[z_1,...,z_d] \in R^d$ is a multivariate random variable, and $x\in R^d$ is another multivariate random variable, and $r(x)=[r_1(x),...,r_d(x)]=[\mathbb{E}[z_1|x],...,\mathbb{E}[z_d|x]] = \mathbb{E}[z|x] \in R^d$ is the conditional expectation.

Also $z_i|x$ and $z_j|x$ are independent for all $i,j$.

There are now two propositions:

- proposition 1: the components of $z$ are independent (*i.e.* $p(z_1,...,z_d)=p(z_1)\cdot...\cdot p(z_d)$)
- proposition 2: the components of $r(x)$ are independent (*i.e.* $p(r_1,...,r_d)=p(r_1)\cdot...\cdot p(r_d)$)

My question is: Does the proposition 1 indicate the proposition 2 or vice versa ?

Comment: This is a bit ill-formed. What would be the object In p(r1, ...,rd)? Joint probability of conditional expectations?

Comment: @MehmetSuzen the conditional expectation $\mathbb{E}(z|x)$ is a function of $x$, since $x$ is a random variable, then $\mathbb{E}(z|x)$ can also be viewed as a random variable. $p(r_1,...,r_d)$ is just the joint probability of the conditional expectations.

Comment: Then it is not possible to say anything on  the relationship between propositions while we don't know how conditional expectations look like functionally.

Comment: @MehmetSuzen Can we get anything if we know that $p(z_i|x)$ admits some concrete distribution (e.g. $z_i|x$ admits gaussian distribution, $z_i|x \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \Sigma)$, where $\Sigma$ is a diagonal matrix) ?